# HTTPD/WSGI/Flask - AH01630: client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am running a flask application with Apache HTTPD + mod_wsgi. The app is working fine but every time a page is accessed there's an error in error_log. (I am trying to optimize the application).

**Error is: AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /apps/apache/httpd_atlas/htdocs/**

HTTPD.conf contains

```
# Block all files by default, unless specifically allowed.
<FilesMatch "^.*$">
  Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

DocumentRoot "/apps/apache/httpd_atlas/htdocs/"

<Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# To enforce IP restrictions on RBB sites - replace [Allow from all] line below with [Allow from <local_ip_address> <TAM_WebSeal_hostname_or_ip>].
# If this site is accessed thru a proxy - you should allow access to the proxy host. If you want to enforce IP restrictions on this site, you
# should configure this on the proxy site. 
<Directory "/apps/apache/httpd_atlas/htdocs/">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<FilesMatch "^.*\.(css|html?|js|pdf|txt|xml|xsl|gif|ico|jpe?g|png)$">
  Require all granted
</FilesMatch>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/apps/apache/httpd_atlas/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/apps/apache/httpd_atlas/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# WSGI Management
WSGIScriptAlias /atlas-test /apps/atlas/atlasda/webapp/toolkit-test/app.wsgi application-group=%<GLOBAL>
WSGIPythonHome /apps/atlas/anaconda
```

Even after this app is served by WSGI correctly, why is error written in error_log and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Can help, if you use cgi, fastcig or fpm as proxy you have to add a location in your vhost to avoid this problem.

```
<Location />
require all granted
</Location>
```